# Strange behavior with bar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm getting strange results when attempting a bar plot:

```
labels = [f'{i+1}/{3}' for i in range(3)]
main_team_values = ['0:05:01', '0:06:54', '0:05:41']
other_team_values = ['0:07:56', '0:07:06', '0:07:04']
X = np.arange(3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(X, main_team_values, color = 'k', width = 0.35)
ax.bar(X + width, other_team_values, color = 'r', width = 0.35)
plt.show()
```

Results in:
[image: plot from text]

As you can see `main_team_values[0]` is omitted from the plot? Does anyone know why?

Also: is there a way for me to label the x-axis with 1/3, 2/3, 3/3 (what I've produced in labels)?

Comment: your values are strings. and the value '0:05:01' corresponds to y=0, so the first plot has a height of 0. Why are you plotting your values as strings? You can even see that the y values are not in order at all, making the bars completely useless. The red bars seem to be increasing, but their y value is actually decreasing

Comment: The values are strings so that the y axis will be labeled in in readable H:MM:SS instead of seconds. Is there a better way around this? @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: I understand that you want to name them in a readable way, but at least you should sort them first. Convert them to a datetime https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-date-string-to-timestamp-in-python/  so you are actually operating with numerical data and not with strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the list you are plotting is string, either convert to timestamps or duration in second and plot

```
main_team_values = [sum(map(lambda x: int(x[0]) * x[1], zip(d.split(':'), [3600, 60, 1])))  for d in main_team_values]
other_team_values = [sum(map(lambda x: int(x[0]) * x[1], zip(d.split(':'), [3600, 60, 1])))  for d in other_team_values]


ax.bar(X, main_team_values, color = 'k', width = 0.35)
ax.bar(X + width, other_team_values, color = 'r', width = 0.35)
plt.ylabel('Time')
fmt = lambda x, y: f"{int(x // 3600):02d}:{int(x%3600) // 60:02d}:{int(x)%60:02d}"
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works, but I want the y-label in MM:SS not seconds.

Comment: just change the label then, I edited the answer